# When I try to rotate/ move (R/G) the armature in pose mode, it doesn’t work. It seemed to connect to the 3D cursor instead

Tags: modeling, animation, armature, pose-mode, 3d-cursor

[image]Video link: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EcR4_RMYL81FsB3VLTp5UPwBtuZfVNfGZTXQyd1Qf1uhPg?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=vtAWHM

The solution I needed is basically just trying to move the armature in the pose mode. I am using skin modifier with armature created and mirror modifier is there as well. And I am not sure if the 3d cursor is the one creating problem there.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: In the Transform Pivot Point panel, switch from 3D Cursor to Median Point? But I'm not sure there's not another problem here if you can't move your bones, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It is solved, I just tried out most of the things testing it around and it just magically happened. The solution is in the top right corner: (Pose option) drop down, I unchecked the (Affect only:Location).

Comment: You can also see the "[X] Only Locations" option when you press the dot button ".", which displays the pivot options mentioned by *moonboots*.